# Angular2 Email Validator not working

Tags: angular

```
 email: [
                this.myService.getUser().info.email,
                Validators.compose([
                    Validators.pattern("[a-zA-Z @]*"),
                    Validators.required
                ])
            ]
```

Above is my email validator and somehow it is not recognizing when I type an at-sign in my text-field.